# How to combine variables of 2 events into one as sum of both. jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I'm trying to create simple price calculator. There are 2 functions which calculates price on select event. How I can sum values of these 2 functions into one, and then add it to ".sum" div ?

```
var xx = j('select[name="miestas"]').change(function(){
    var kainos = {"vln":"55", "kns":"150"};
    var val = j(this).find(":selected").text();
    kaina1 = kainos[val];
    return kaina1;
});

var zz = j('select[name="vardas"]').change(function(){
    var kainos = {"vln":"35", "kns":"30"};
    var val = j(this).find(":selected").text();
    kaina2 = kainos[val];
    return kaina2;
});


    j('select').change(function(){
    j('.sum').html(zz + xx); });
```

Comment: maybe http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/ dont know if change event is supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't return anything from those functions, assign the result to some global variables:

```
var xx;
var zz;
```

and inside the handlers:

```
...
xx = Number(kaina1);

...
zz = Number(kaina2);
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/txkmD/1/